# How to match one column and replace a different (corresponding) column in another sheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets within a google spreadsheet, one with original data and two columns (name, category) and one with recategorized data (name, new category).

I am hoping to use an apps script to find all the names that are listed in the recategorized sheet in the original sheet, and subsequently replace all of the corresponding categories with the new category from the recategorized data sheet. In other words, match 'name' across the two sheets, and replace 'category' in sheet 1 with 'new category' from sheet two.

Not all of the names in the original sheet will be included in the recategorized data sheet, it will likely only find and replace a few entries.

I am very new to Apps Scripts so am not sure where to start.

For example, if 'broccoli' is categorized as 'vegetable' and pear is categorized as 'fruit' in the original sheet, but in the 2nd sheet 'broccoli' is categorized as 'bitter' and pear as 'sweet', I would like the app to replace 'vegetable' and 'fruit' with 'bitter' and 'sweet' respectively in the original sheet.

Comment: Hi. Would you please share your spreadsheet? This should answer the question of how many rows of data you have in each sheet. Would you also indicate, is this is one-time adjustment, or something that you would run periodically (and if, so, how often)..Lastly, you anticipate using a script, but why not use `vlookup` with an appropriate `if` statement?

Comment: Something like this should do the trick: Enter in Sheet1-ColC, first row of data `=vlookup(A3,'5664033702'!$A$3:$B$7,2,false)`. Copy the formula down as many rows as you have data in Sheet1-ColA. Then `Copy/Paste Special, Values Only` the new values over the old values in Sheet1-ColB.

Comment: Hi @tedinoz, thanks for your answer. Here is the [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQA8mwow9oh2AcndcnVBEU6YUQqqFCRTlObDUktGkJs/edit?usp=sharing) to a sample data set.

I would like to make these adjustments periodically, maybe every few months, which is why I thought a script might be better. But I am open to recommendations. 

As for vlookup, I thought it might not work since I am not using the left most category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function adds the new categories to the first sheet which in my case is Sheet1.  I could have just as easily replaced the first with the second category in Sheet 1 but this way it's easier to tell whether the function caught the correct data.

```
function findCats() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,sh1.getLastColumn()+1);
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(2,1,sh2.getLastRow()-1,sh2.getLastColumn());
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  var obj2={nA:[]};
  for(var i=0;i<vA2.length;i++) {
    obj2[vA2[i][0]]=vA2[i][1];
    obj2.nA.push(vA2[i][0]);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++) {
    var idx=obj2.nA.indexOf(vA1[i][0]);
    if(idx>-1) {
      vA1[i][2]=obj2[vA1[i][0]];
    }
  }
  rg1.setValues(vA1);
}
```

Sheet 1 before:

[image]

Sheet2 before:

[image]

Sheet1 after running function:

[image]

---

Amendment to reflect layout of spreadsheet and update of the Category2 column

---

```
function so5664033702() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var tarsheet=ss.getSheetByName('Old Categories');
  var tarLC =tarsheet.getLastColumn();
  var tarLR = tarsheet.getLastRow();
  var tarRange=tarsheet.getRange(2,1,tarLR-1,tarLC);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Target range ="+tarRange.getA1Notation());
  var tarValues=tarRange.getValues();
  // get the Cat2 values so that the range can be easily updated after the loop
  var tarcat2Range = tarsheet.getRange(2,6,tarLR-1);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Target Cat2 range ="+tarcat2Range.getA1Notation());
  var tarcat2Values = tarcat2Range.getValues();
  var srcsheet=ss.getSheetByName('New Categories');
  var srcLR = srcsheet.getLastRow();
  var srcRange=srcsheet.getRange(2,1,srcLR-1,3);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Source Range ="+srcRange.getA1Notation());
  var srcValues=srcRange.getValues();
  // create array to build names  
  var tarNames = [];
// loop through Old Category Names to pupulate the array  
  for (z=0;z<tarValues.length;z++){
    tarNames.push(tarValues[z][1]);
  }   
  // loop through the new category Names to find the match on Old Categories
  // the value "c" will be the row number.
  for (i=0;i<srcValues.length;i++){
    var c = tarNames.indexOf(srcValues[i][0]);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: c = "+c+", value: "+srcValues[i][0]+", cat2:"+tarcat2Values[c][0] +", new Cat2:"+srcValues[i][2]);
    // if c = -1, then there is no match; otherwise update the OldCategory/category2 value with the value from New category
    if (c!=-1){
      tarcat2Values[c][0] = srcValues[i][2];      
    }
  } // end of the New category Loop
  // setValues for the Cat2 range with the updated values.
  tarcat2Range.setValues(tarcat2Values); 
}
```

---

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for submitting this answer. It is definitely a step in the right direction, however I definitely would like to replace the data in the first sheet with the data in the second. Also, in my data set, the columns are not side by side. Here is a sample sheet for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQA8mwow9oh2AcndcnVBEU6YUQqqFCRTlObDUktGkJs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JasmineCooper I've looked at your sample sheet and re-read your question and, at face value, I would have agreed with Cooper. I think your sample sheet needs a "model answer" to remove any/all confusion about language.

Comment: @tedinoz thanks for double checking. I've updated the sheet with a "model answer" (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQA8mwow9oh2AcndcnVBEU6YUQqqFCRTlObDUktGkJs/edit?usp=sharing) Hopefully this adds some clarity. Unfortunately I can't get Cooper's solution to work, potentially because the column/row numbers don't line up. Apologies, I am a rookie and can't seem to figure it out! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JasmineCooper That's great, thank you. So it is not merely matching the "name", one must also match the "old" category as well. OK, I don't think that was necessarily obvious before, but we can work with that.

Comment: Great - glad that helped. The "new category" column in sheet 2 is manually entered, so ideally a script would scan for all instances of 'apple' in sheet 1 and replace 'fruit' in column F with 'sweet' for all instances of 'apple'. Not sure if this requires matching the 'old category', but I could be mistaken!

Comment: @JasmineCooper It does require matching the old category; how else would one know which of the three category columns to update?

Comment: @tedinoz We are always replacing category 2 (Col F) with this data set. We can ignore the other two categories and keep their original data.

Comment: @JasmineCooper Argh ;) These are the little tid-bits that you "assumed" and as a result you didn't include/describe in your question; and they can save a LOT of wasted time. I do hope that this will have been a learning experience for you in terms of writing a question that contains ALL the relevant information.

Comment: @JasmineCooper  Refer amendments in the source. (may take a while before you can see it).

Comment: @tedinoz Thank you! Really appreciate it, and yes, will definitely learn and be more specific in the future.

Comment: The code seems to be working in replacing categories, although it doesn't seem to replace every instance. I'm working on tweaking it today to ensure it replaces all of the old categories and not just the first appearance. I'll post it here if resolved

Comment: @JasmineCooper _although it doesn't seem to replace every instance_ If you'd give me an example in terms of the test data, I'll double check. There was one assumption: "Carrot" was not changed on "Old Categories" because it was not listed in "New Categories".

Comment: @tedinoz For example, if there is a second iteration of apple, categorized as fruit in category 2...Only the first 'apple''s category will change to sweet. The second 'apple''s category will remain as fruit.

This is probably another instance of me failing to mention that there could be multiple apples in the list, so no worries if you do not have the time, you have been very helpful already!

Comment: @JasmineCooper Would you update your model answer to reflect the updated “Old Categories”. Thanks. _This is probably another instance of ..._ Surely not ;)

Comment: @Tedinoz Sure! Should be all set. I just duplicated the prior set so the rows are in the same order, but ideally the script could rename categories regardless of the order of each name.

Comment: @JasmineCooper I've updated the code. The key is line 25 where it loops though the names on "Old categories", and line 29 `var c = tarNames.indexOf(srcValues[i][0],x);`. The value of "x" increments so that it will look (and find) for multiple instances of the "Name" - and wherever it finds a instance (multiple of not), it updates the value in Column F.

Comment: @Tedinoz Perfect - this works, thanks for the explanation as well! Really appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: No worries. I was, as always, inspired by Cooper’s work. If you think this answer was helpful, then you might consider “accepting” it